# DRF: serializer validation without a model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is the `validate_fieldname` method not called when not using a `ModelSerializer`? I am trying to validate my input:

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   serial = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ["serial",]

    def validate_serial(self, value):
        if value ... 
        return value
```

I want to use a validator method on the input of `serial`, but I do not have a related model I could use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. The [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation) helps. It is not necessary to use a model.